# Template classes and calling different constructors depending on iteration

Tags: c++, class, templates, entities, entity-component-system

I am learning ECS and I am now trying to implement components for my project.

So to put you in context, I have an aquarium, and many components in it (let's say seaweeds and fish). Both have an age, but only fishes have a race.

I have a class for general_components (age and other stuff) and a class for fish-specific components (race, sex, etc).

I made a template components class with a create method that looks like that:

```
template<typename ConcreteComponent> // ConcreteComponent is attached to the class
ConcreteComponent& Components<ConcreteComponent>::create( entity e ) {
    m_components.push_back( ConcreteComponent(e) );
    return m_components.back();
}
```

The problem I have is I want to be able to call different constructors depending on what class I have (instead of entity e right here, which is generic to every class in my setup), but while staying the most efficient way (so with templates and no copy paste for every class). For my problem it wouldn't be the end of the world but in general if I faced this again I want to be prepared.

Is there a way to call a create function with different parameters?

For example:

```
A<fishComponents> myClassIter;
myClassIter.create("name", age, race, sex)
```

For fishes would pass `"name",age,race,sex` to `ConcreteComponent()` constructor instead of only `e` (And I have a `"name",age,race,sex` constructor for `fishComponents`).

TL;DR: in a template class method, is it possible to pass a different number and nature of values to the constructor of the class used depending on the parameters

```
template<typename A>
void myClass<A>::create( list_of_parameters) {
A(list_of_parameters) /*calls the constructor of the template class A */
}
```

I saw something like that in C but it was recommended not to touch it as it was dated and not used any more.

Comment: Can you use C++11 or later?  This looks like it'd be simple with parameter packs and `std::forward`.

Comment: I can, my compiler is set to c++17 right now, I will take a look at these things! I am quite new to programming so I still don't know most of the stuff

Comment: Are you aware of type erasure occurring if your vector is of type `std::vector<BaseComponent>`?

Comment: I am not sure of what you mean by type erasure, but if it is about not being able to sort them by the nature of the Component, then everything in my program is based on an unique ID for each entity, so it is not a problem (I was not aware of "type erasure" and I based my idea on this link : http://davekilian.com/cpp-type-erasure.html)

Comment: @Tommy-XavierRobillard Ah, sorry, correct term would have been [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). As you clarified in comment to answer, you have different vectors for different objects, so won't occur. Confusion would have been avoided by an [mcve]...

Comment: Yes, this is what I tried to do in the TLDR but I get that it isn't really clear. Thank you for pointing it out! And thank you for the link, great insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is to use parameter packs and `std::forward` to pass along whatever arguments come in to the real constructor.  A complete but simplified example (no data structures and one argument per type) is below:

```
#include <iostream>

class Fish {
public:
    Fish(std::string const &name) {
        std::cout << "Making a fish named " << name << '\n';
    }
};

class Seaweed {
public:
    Seaweed(int length) {
        std::cout << "Making a seaweed that's " << length << " feet long\n";
    }
};

template <typename ConcreteComponent, typename ...ARGS>
ConcreteComponent create(ARGS && ...args) {
    return ConcreteComponent(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    create<Fish>("Bob");
    create<Seaweed>(42);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./forwarding
Making a fish named Bob
Making a seaweed that's 42 feet long
```

It's worth reading about `std::forward`, but what we're basically doing here is taking everything that comes in to `create` and passing it along to the type's constructor, while also preserving properties about the type (e.g., whether it's a temporary or not).  Thus, you can pass *anything*, so long as there's a valid constructor to pass things on to.

My code was tested with g++-7.3.0 using C++11, 14, and 17.

Comment: I will definetely look deeper into this, I am not the kind of person to do stuff I don't understand, and this seems really useful. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You had better use the inheritance of class which is used in Oriented-Object programming.

Build a base class and its inherited classes, so the generated inherited classes' objects can produced by their different properties dynamically.

Comment: Well in the exercise (which is in french: https://zestedesavoir.com/forums/sujet/447/javaquarium/) they state in the comments that it was a good idea to try it ECS style (and that's what I'm learning anyway) because we then have to implement all sort of methods (for example eat( eater, target ) will have different inputs depending if the eater is herbivore or carnivore, so it's harder to do that way

Comment: @Tommy-XavierRobillard Did I miss someting? You do not seem to be using [ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html) so far anyway. Am I on the correct link? You try placing different elements into a `std::vector` only. But as these elements are of different type, Yang's approach is the way to go. Be aware that the vector needs to manage *pointers* to the common base class, otherwise type erasure will occur!

Comment: @Aconcagua I didn't want to expand myself: I started the exercise like this github.com/TommyXR/Aquarium_old but then finding that it was messy with all the namespaces and everything I decided to start from scratch with classes instead, and here I am  **Plus I am not sure of what you mean. I will have one different vector for each type. My vectors are not heterogenous

Comment: @Tommy-XavierRobillard OK, so then forget my comment - with different vectors, object slicing (which would have been the correct term right from the start) won't occur, I assumed you wanted to place all objects into the same vector. If you discover this being a useful feature, though, then come back to this answer...